# How to set margin with ViewPager filling the parent

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, margins

I have some problems with my application. I have the next activity:

[image]

This activity has a ViewPager (the rounded rectangle with the gradient colour) and I need to set margins or padding to right and left. I thought in this solution:

```
<ViewPager
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
```

Doing this, but adding margin only to right, it looks like:

[image]

But this is a problem because I get the next results when swipping the screen:

[image]

As you can see, the fragment doesn't appears from the screen limit, but it appears from the margin I set to ViewPager.

What I need is to have the ViewPager filling the parent horizontally but with the rounded rectangle limited by right and left due to some kind of margin.

I have already tried to set the margin directly to the fragment's XML code but it doesn't reflects any effect.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: try using padding for both Right & Left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the layout with the rounded corners is the layout your viewpager calls, try to create a linearlayout inside your current layout and add the margins inside this one. 
I hope this helps you, or it may inspire you a solution.

Comment: Yeees! It was the solution! It works! Thank you EinarMU.